# char pointer becomes null within the pass of function calls

Tags: string, pointers, null, gdb, char

```
(5) 0x1c6235e1 in ProxyClass::Method_C (this=0xb3a0c8, sendFilePath=...) at ./src/ProxyClass.cpp:112

(6) 0x2c8706c1 in Class1::Method_B (this=0x1fc5a1, profile=0x2c8f2340 "fileProfile1", filePathAndFileName=0x0) at ./src/Class1.cpp:860

(7) 0x2c4ae4c0 in Method_B (profile=0x42c <Address 0x42c out of bounds>, filePathAndFileName=0x0) at ./src/Class1_interface.cpp:310

(8) 0x2c1e5c3c in Method_A (profile=0x42c <Address 0x42c out of bounds>, filename=0x2c601c1c "/tmp/temporaryfile.tmp") at ./src/file.cpp:890
```

I have the above core file snippet that is debugged with gnu gdb. This core file is created on an embedded system running Linux. There is no manipulation to the variables within the function calls...
My questions are below:

1. How come the profile looks like `Address 0x42c out of bounds` on 8th frame and while there is no change to profile until the 9th frame how can that become something meaningful("fileSchema")?
2. My embedded system crashes because the `filename(char *)` equals to `0x2c601c1c` and the path is printed like this on the 8 th frame "/tmp/temporaryfile.tmp". However, again without manipulation to filename variable, Method_A calls Method_B but the char pointer suddenly becomes null on 7th frame (filePathAndFileName=0x0). Then, my system crashes. How can that char * pointer transforms to NULL with manipulation?

The crash occurs on the 6th frame because in `Class1::Method_B` the following line is executed `"std::string filePath( filePathAndFileName);"`. A null char pointer is being tried to get initialized to a string and I think it causes the crash and the Abort signal (Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.). How can I avoid that char * to become null within the pass of that variable between the methods? Any idea why it becomes null?

```
static TUint16 Method_A(char* profile, char* filename)
{
    TUint16 a; //after the call of Method_B,the other part of this method being processed but anyway the code never passes to there because of th crash..
    Method_B(profile,filename);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return a;
}

unsigned char Method_B_interface(char* profile, char* filePathAndFileName)
{
    unsigned char returnValue = 0;

    if ( callbackObject->Method_B( profile, filePathAndFileName ) )
    {
        returnValue = 1;
    }
    return returnValue;
}

bool Class1::Method_B(char* profile, char* filePathAndFileName)
{
    bool returnValue = true;

    std::string   filePathString( filePathAndFileName );
    std::string   profileString( profile );

    if(profileString == "fileProfile1")
    {
        if(xClass != NULL)
        {
            returnValue = xClass->Method_C(filePathString);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return returnValue;
}

bool ProxyClass::Method_C(const std::string& exportFilePathAndFileName)
{
    bool returnValue;
    std::string message = "dummy", parameters;

    Serializer::serialize( message, exportFilePathAndFileName );
    proxyRequest->synchCall( message, parameters );

    getResponse(parameters);
    Serializer::deserialize( parameters, returnValue );

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: Do you need any specific file or all of them?

Comment: `Method_C()` and `Method_B()` seem most useful.